# i want to change header position static to fixed with smooth slide down effect

Tags: jquery

```
>     when i scroll then header will animate with slide down effect and position changed to
>     fixed else with slide up effect and change position to static back
```

1. First problem is after slide up div goes hide i want to  show div where it
   is after slide up
2. Second problem is slide down not working properly

[js Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/trvfhyq7/2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scroll <= 380) {
       $('.header').slideDown(function(){
          $('.header').css('position','fixed');
       });

    }else{
        $('.header').slideUp();
    }
});
```

```css
.main{height:1300px;}
.header{width:100%; height:70px; background-color:red; margin:auto;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
    <div class="header"><h1>header</h1></div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {

    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (scroll >= 380) {
        if($('.header').css("position") != "fixed")
      $('.header').css({position:"fixed",top:"-70px"}).animate({top:"0",},100,"linear")
    }else if (scroll <= 180) {
        if($('.header').css("position") != "static")
      $('.header').animate({top:"-70px",},100,"linear",function(){
                $('.header').css({position:"static"})
            })
    }
});
```

```css
.main{height:1300px;}
.header{width:1000px; height:70px; background-color:red; margin:auto;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
    <div class="header"><h1>header</h1></div>
</div>
```

Comment: i want header slide down after some scroll then slide up bt no changes in my static header

Comment: if i have understand you want: after scroll down the header slideUp and after scroll up the header scrollDown. is correct?

Comment: for example i have a static header i don't won't to make any changes on this, bt when i scroll >=300 header slide down , <=300 slide up ,bt no changes in my static header,and i don't won't to make clone of my header

Comment: Ok, you say `static' but  you want the header is fixed on top. just?

Comment: when page load static header ,when i scroll >=180 header slide down position fixed, one more thing  below<=180  header slide up ,bt no changes in static header, hope u understand

Comment: u can see this effect in snapdeal homepage

Comment: Ok. on snapdeal homepage they use 2 block header. One is static header and the other is for dynamic header. Ok please try: http://jsfiddle.net/j2p1r573/

Comment: i know they use 2 block header but i don't won't to use two block header, the reason is ajax support only one header ,if i call that block two times ajax will updated only first one, even if i make clone my header then ajax will support only first one not clone, finally the result is ajax support only one header at the time, thats why i won't this effect on single header

Comment: i m using multiple ajax extension in magento they only support one header at a time

Comment: thank bro u save my day that is exactly what i want, thanks alot